# In iPhone and iPad label and SpanLabel not aligned properly(slight difference)

Tags: ios, label, codenameone

I'm having issues displaying Labels aligned properly. Please advise Please find the screenshots and Code. Right screenshot refers android device is the correct way to display and left one from iphone.

Code:

```
Container table = new Container(new TableLayout(6, 2));                    
Label firstNameLbl = new Label("First Name ");
firstNameLbl.setUIID("StringLbl");
table.add(firstNameLbl).add(givenName);
Label lastNameLbl = new Label("Last Name ");
lastNameLbl.setUIID("StringLbl");
table.add(lastNameLbl).add(surname);
Label refNumberLbl = new Label("Ref. Number ");
refNumberLbl.setUIID("StringLbl");
table.add(refNumberLbl).add(refnum);
Label cellPhoneLbl = new Label("Cell Phone ");
cellPhoneLbl.setUIID("StringLbl");
Label homePhoneLbl = new Label("Home Phone ");
homePhoneLbl.setUIID("StringLbl");
Label workPhoneLbl = new Label("Work Phone ");
workPhoneLbl.setUIID("StringLbl");
SpanLabel cellPhoneSpan = new SpanLabel(cellPhone);
cellPhoneSpan.setUIID("SpanLabel");
SpanLabel homePhoneSpan = new SpanLabel(homePhone);
homePhoneSpan.setUIID("SpanLabel");
SpanLabel workPhoneSpan = new SpanLabel(workPhone);
workPhoneSpan.setUIID("SpanLabel");
table.add(cellPhoneLbl).add(cellPhoneSpan).add(homePhoneLbl).
add(homePhoneSpan).add(workPhoneLbl).add(workPhoneSpan);
setSameHeight(cellPhoneLbl, cellPhoneSpan, homePhoneLbl, homePhoneSpan, workPhoneLbl, workPhoneSpan);
```

Android Screenshot
[image: Android screenshot]
iPhone Screenshot
[image: iPhone Screenshot]

[image: iphone screenshot]
[image: Android Screenshot]

Comment: Can you please point exactly where you see issue. or share snapshot from device.

Comment: @Stakshi I just added screenshot and code

Comment: I would suggest you to use story board for UI.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
cellPhoneSpan.setUIID("Container");
cellPhoneSpan.setTextUIID("StringLbl");
```

The `SpanLabel` is a bit more complex so it's possible you double padded this class inadvertently. `SpanLabel` is effectively a `Container` that has a `TextArea` styled to look like a `Label`. So you might get padding both from the external `Container` and from the internal `TextArea`.

These things are easy to spot with the `Component Inspector` tool you can launch in the simulator. You can view the hierarchy and see the UIID's, padding, margin etc. of every component in the tree.

Comment: Code did not work Shai. This is only happening on apple devices. I dont see any difference in Component Inspector.

Comment: Make sure you didn't invoke setUIID on the same component over again afterwards. Also make sure you didn't override the styling for Container which would be a big mistake.  Another potential workaround is to use a `SpanLabel` for the label on the left too and that way they will be perfectly aligned

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use story board for UI. But in case that is not option. Try visualizing layout. or by setting background color for each field. My suspicion is that one of Work phone label is top aligned but span label is bottom aligned. correcting alignment should fix issue you are facing.

Comment: Both the labels have same alignment but still on iPhone there is slight difference in the alignment occurs. On android phone it displays correctly. please advise if any other thing causing this issue.

Comment: Shai Almog is probably right. did you try assigning background colors different to each row and background. Its hacky way to debug in some cases it has helped me to clearly see UI. I wish i could be of more help